# Threaded TrafficLightExample numerous threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, enums

I am doing an example in a book and it has a threaded example in which a traffic light is simulated. I understand most of the program, however, I am confused about the portion in which the book says " a seperate thread will run each traffic light", it appears that only one thread was created in the main application?
I have an enumeration that lists all the constants of my traffic light.

```
public enum TrafficLightColor {
YELLOW,GREEN,RED
}
```

Here is the rest of the program.

```
public class TrafficLightSimulator implements Runnable {
private Thread thread;//holds the thread that runs the simulation
private TrafficLightColor color;//holds the traffic light color
boolean stop=false;//set to true to stop the simulation 
boolean changed=false;//true when the light has changed
public TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor inital){
color=inital;
thread=new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}
public TrafficLightSimulator(){
color=TrafficLightColor.RED;
thread=new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    //start up the light
    while(!stop){
        try{
            switch(color){
            case GREEN:
                Thread.sleep(10000);//green sleeps for 10 seconds
                break;
            case RED:
                Thread.sleep(2000);//yellow for 2 seconds
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                Thread.sleep(12000);//red for 12 seconds
                break;

            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        changeColor();
    }
}
synchronized void changeColor(){
    switch(color){
    case RED:
        color=TrafficLightColor.GREEN;
        break;
    case YELLOW:    
        color=TrafficLightColor.RED;
        break;
    case GREEN:
        color=TrafficLightColor.YELLOW;     
    }
    changed=true;
    System.out.println("Notfiy Called We changed the light");
    notify();
}
synchronized void waitForChange(){
    try{
        while(!changed){
            System.out.println("waiting for Light to change");
            wait();
        }
        changed=false;

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
synchronized TrafficLightColor getColor(){
    return color;
}
synchronized void cancel(){
    stop=true;
}

}
 class Demo{
public static void main(String[]args){
    TrafficLightSimulator t1=new     TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor.YELLOW);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        System.out.println(t1.getColor());
        t1.waitForChange();
    }
    t1.cancel();
}
}
```

Comment: There are two threads, the program's main thread and the traffic simulator thread, maybe the book has a typo and they meant *a seperate thread will run each traffic simulator*

Comment: Why do the mehtods need to be synchronized if their is only one thread operating on the TrafficLightSimulator?

Comment: Or I guess the other thread is the main thread that is communicating with the TrafficLightSimulator thread?

Comment: Yes, the other thread is the program's main thread, they use the synchronized because the simulator thread and the main thread will access the "changed" variable (through the waitForChange function) and they also access to the "color" and "stop" variables.

Comment: Method `main` starts main thread, `TrafficLightSimulator` starts its own separate thread. Methods marked `synchronized` to ensure thread-safety, though in this example they are called from one thread.

Comment: @doge the protected vars are accesed from two threads, main thread (through waitForChange, getColor and cancel functions) and the simulator's thread.

Comment: Indeed they both operate with data in TrafficLightSimulator.

Comment: _a seperate thread will run each traffic light_  Be aware that while that might be a good way to learn something about _how_ to coordinate the activities of threads, it's a really awful example of _why_ to do it.  If your goal was to simulate a system of traffic lights (or, to actually run a _real_ set of traffic lights), you'd probably be better off with a timed, event-driven architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Print a name of the thread in each `println` command, it shows you which thread is executing which part of the code, and it helps you to understand what's going on.
Just:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "==>"
                    + "Notfiy Called We changed the light");
```

If you run the application, you will get:

```
Thread-0==> start up the light
main==>YELLOW
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>RED
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>GREEN
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>YELLOW
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>RED
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>GREEN
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>YELLOW
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>RED
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
main==>GREEN
main==>waiting for Light to change
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
Thread-0==>Notfiy Called We changed the light
```

There is always a **main** thread in each java application - this thread is created by the Java virtual machine, and the main thread executes the application code (calling `public static void main()` method).
The application can create and start other threads - in your code it's name is `Thread-0` and it is created and started in the constructor - here:

```
public TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor inital) {
    color = inital;
    thread = new Thread(this);  // creates a new thread
    thread.start();             // starts the new thread
}
```

Please copy, paste and run this code, it has `Thread.currentThread().getName() + "==>"` included in each `println` command:

```
public class TrafficLightSimulator implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;// holds the thread that runs the simulation
    private TrafficLightColor color;// holds the traffic light color
    boolean stop = false;// set to true to stop the simulation
    boolean changed = false;// true when the light has changed

    public TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor inital) {
        color = inital;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public TrafficLightSimulator() {
        color = TrafficLightColor.RED;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // start up the light
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +"==>" +" start up the light" );
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                switch (color) {
                case GREEN:
                    Thread.sleep(10000);// green sleeps for 10 seconds
                    break;
                case RED:
                    Thread.sleep(2000);// yellow for 2 seconds
                    break;
                case YELLOW:
                    Thread.sleep(12000);// red for 12 seconds
                    break;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            changeColor();
        }
    }

    synchronized void changeColor() {
        switch (color) {
        case RED:
            color = TrafficLightColor.GREEN;
            break;
        case YELLOW:
            color = TrafficLightColor.RED;
            break;
        case GREEN:
            color = TrafficLightColor.YELLOW;
        }
        changed = true;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "==>" + "Notfiy Called We changed the light");
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void waitForChange() {
        try {
            while (!changed) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "==>" +  "waiting for Light to change");
                wait();
            }
            changed = false;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    synchronized TrafficLightColor getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    synchronized void cancel() {
        stop = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrafficLightSimulator t1 = new TrafficLightSimulator(TrafficLightColor.YELLOW);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "==>" + t1.getColor());
            t1.waitForChange();
        }
        t1.cancel();
    }

}
```